Is the following statement trivial?
If for all A and B, it is satisfiable that A is a mathematical structure and B is a cardinal number, then one of the As has the same cardinality as B.

This depends on what you mean by a "mathematical structure," but probably the answer is yes. Is a set a "mathematical structure"? If so, then yes, since every cardinal number is the cardinal number of a set. Is an abelian group a "mathematical structure"? If so, then yes, since every cardinal number is the cardinal number of an abelian group. Is a topological space a "mathematical structure"? If so, then yes, since every cardinal number is the cardinal number of a topological space.

no, every monoid must have an identity element.

OK, that's true, I should have said that every nonzero cardinal number is the cardinal number of an abelian group. Anyway some types of structure are more constrained: for example, there's no Boolean algebra with precisely 3 elements. Not sure whether this is the kind of thing the OP is after.

What about the following though: For all X, if it is satisfiable that X is a boolean algebra, then at least one Boolean Algebra has precisely three elements.

@AUTISTINC There is no Boolean algebra with precisely 3 elements, so the consequent of your conditional cannot be satisfied.

Hold on, there’s a problem with that though. Since the consequent is false, then the antecedent is false. But the antecedent is not false though. Not unless you’re saying the conditional is false.

@AUTISTINC I did not try to address your antecedent because I do not know what your antecedent is supposed to mean. What do you intend for the variable X to range over? The von Neumann universe? Also, by "it is satisfiable that X is a Boolean algebra" do you mean "X is the underlying set of a Boolean algebra"? If this is indeed what you mean, then the antecedent of your conditional is false, since there exists a set which is not the underlying set of a Boolean algebra, e.g. any set with precisely 3 elements.

Here’s what I mean by satisfiable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability?wprov=sfti1#

Is there a philosophical motive here? I'd suspect that this can be given more concrete answers at Math SE.
